# Getting a java.sql.SqlNonTransientConnectionException

Tags: java, derby, javadb

I am rather new to Java and JavaDB. I am trying to create a database in Netbeans 7.0.1 and after the server starts, I get an error that says:

"An error occurred while creating the database: java.sql.SqlNonTransientConnectionException: A communications error has been detected: Software caused connection abort: recv failed.."

I have tried to disable my antivirus (Microsoft Security Essentials) and my Windows Firewall, as well as disable an internet filter(Contentwatch's NetNanny) all to no avail.

Is there something I'm missing? Google is no help either.

Comment: Can you post the database connection properties that you're using?

Comment: The JavaDB is located in my program files/glassfish folder, I am using the default port 1527, and I am putting the database into my users folder. I am using Windows 7.